# Setting up crypto++

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, crypto++

I downloaded crypto++ 5.6.2 (the zip file) and built it using just `make` (I have gcc 4.8.1). It seemed to work and gave me a `libcryptopp.a` file.

Now, to test the setup, I tried to compile the `test.cpp` file that was provided with the download (link here: http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/test_8cpp_source.html).

First, I compiled it with

`g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -g -Iinclude -I/c/libraries/cryptopp562 -c test.cpp -o obj/test.o`

which gave a lot of warnings (deprecations and unused variables mostly) but worked and I got the `test.o` file.

Now, to link it, I used

`g++ obj/test.o -o bin/test -L/c/libraries/cryptopp562 -lcryptopp`

But this gave a lot of `undefined reference` errors and failed.

For example

`` D:\.../test.cpp:119: undefined reference to `RegisterFactories()' ``

But when you look at the `test.cpp` file (http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/test_8cpp_source.html), there is only the declaration to `RegisterFactories()`, but no definition. Does this mean, it needs to find it from the library? (A local declaration shouldn't be needed in this case, no?)

Ok, so what do I have to do to get the whole library to work? Use `gmake` to build it? Or use an older `gcc`? Or maybe my compile/link commands are incorrect?

Comment: The sample you have linked seems to require a bunch of further libraries like `md5`, `sockets`, etc.

Comment: Isn't `test.cpp` part of the library? You should use `make test` or similar commands to compile and run it instead of manually compiling it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Setting up crypto++

The instructions to setup Crypto++ under Linux are on the wiki at [Build and Install the Library](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Linux#Build_and_Install_the_Library).

---

> ... to test the setup, I tried to compile the `test.cpp` ...

If you want to build the test suite, then you run `make cryptest.exe`.

If you want to run the test suite after building it, you run `./cryptest.exe v`.

---

> `undefined reference to RegisterFactories()`

There are 9 source files that are used in the test suite. They are:

- validate.h, bench.h
- test.cpp, datatest.cpp
- bench.cpp, bench2.cpp
- validat1.cpp, validat2.cpp, validat3.cpp

---

> ... what do I have to do to get the whole library to work?

`make cryptest.exe` and `./cryptest.exe v` usually work fine :)

I usually run `make static dynamic cryptest.exe` to build both the static archive and the shared object.

You can also run individual test with `tv` command. For example, `./cryptest.exe tv sha1` will run SHA-1 related tests. `tv` is "test vectors", and they are located in the `TestVectors" directory of the sources.

---

Related, if you want the test suite to run after installation, then you will need the [DataDir Patch](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Datadir).

Its a patch supplied by the community. Its not part of the Crypto++ library (though it should probably be part of the library).

Answer (score 0):

test.cpp is not self-contained. It used a lot of other files. Actually it is already used in the build (see GNUmakefile). After the build, libcryptopp.a and cryptest.exe are generated. test.cpp is used in building cryptest.exe.

The specific function you mentioned is defined in regtest.cpp. It also uses a lot of other functions in other C++ files.